# Selecting correct price given purchase date and effective price dates

Tags: sql-server

I need a query to find the price of an item at the time of its purchase; the prices change over time.
I have two tables linked by a foreign key:

```
table Albums:
ID  Name    PurchaseDate
1   Album1  2014-05-14
2   Album2  2014-05-14
3   Album3  2014-05-14
```

and

```
table Prices:
ID  AlbumID Price   EffDate
1   1       5.00    2014-01-01
2   2       5.00    2014-01-01
3   3       5.00    2014-01-01
4   3       60.00   2014-04-25
5   3       700.00  2014-12-12
```

When I join the tables with this query:

```
select a.ID, a.Name, a.PurchaseDate, p.Price, p.EffDate
from Albums a
inner join Prices p
on a.ID=p.AlbumID;
```

I get the following result:

```
ID  Name    PurchaseDate  Price  EffDate
1   Album1  2014-05-14    5.00   2014-01-01
2   Album2  2014-05-14    5.00   2014-01-01
3   Album3  2014-05-14    5.00   2014-01-01
3   Album3  2014-05-14    60.00  2014-04-25
3   Album3  2014-05-14    700.00 2014-12-12
```

The problem is the multiple results for Album3. It's easy to get rid of the record with the EffDate in the future:

```
select a.ID, a.Name, a.PurchaseDate, p.Price, p.EffDate
from Albums a
inner join Prices p
on a.ID=p.AlbumID 
where p.EffDate <= a.PurchaseDate;
```

Which gives the following result:

```
ID  Name    PurchaseDate  Price  EffDate
1   Album1  2014-05-14    5.00   2014-01-01
2   Album2  2014-05-14    5.00   2014-01-01
3   Album3  2014-05-14    5.00   2014-01-01
3   Album3  2014-05-14    60.00  2014-04-25
```

But I need to select only one record for each Album, i.e. the one with the most current EffDate given the PurchaseDates of 2014-05-14 (namely 60.00 on 2014-04-25 for Album3). 
I thought to myself, "that should be easy!" But I just can't figure it out! I've tried DISTINCT, aggregates with MAX(EffDate), common table expressions, ROW_NUMBER () with PARTITION BY and ORDER BY clauses, FIRST_VALUE (Price) OVER ( ... ), and combinations of all these, and I'm still stumped! (And probably also just plain-old-dumb!) Here are two of my *many* failed attempts:

Attempt A:

```
WITH cte AS
(
    select a.ID, a.Name, a.PurchaseDate, p.Price, p.EffDate
    from Albums a
    inner join Prices p
    on a.ID=p.AlbumID
    where p.EffDate <= a.PurchaseDate
)
select ID, Name, PurchaseDate, Price, MaxED = (select max(EffDate) from cte)
from cte;
```

---This query and other similar variants gives the exact same results as the previous listing!!!! The aggregate function max(EffDate) apparently has no effect on CTE results?!

Attempt B:

```
select a.ID, a.Name, a.PurchaseDate, p.Price, p.EffDate, pseq
from Albums a
inner join 
    (select p.*, row_number() over (partition by AlbumID order by EffDate) as pseq
    from Prices p) p
on a.ID=p.AlbumID
where p.EffDate <= a.PurchaseDate;
```

---This query also gives the exact same result as above (except for the extra column 'pseq')!

Solutions in other similar posts such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056633/get-correct-price-based-on-effectivity-date) have not worked with my situation.

Sorry for the long post, but I thought it important to set the example and my requirements clearly, along with some of my failures.  Please Help!

**P.S.**: I'm using MS SQLEXPRESS 2014 and SSMS. And yes, my actual tables and queries are a lot more complex than this example, but the example presents my underlying problem as succinctly as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this would give you the actual price:

```
select 
a.ID, 
a.Name, 
a.PurchaseDate, 
(select top 1 p.Price from Prices p where p.AlbumId = a.Id and p.EffDate <= a.PurchaseDate  order by p.EffDate desc) as 'Price'
from Albums a
```

Output:

```
ID          Name                 PurchaseDate            Price
----------- -------------------- ----------------------- ---------------------------------------
1           Album1               2014-05-14 00:00:00.000 5.00
2           Album2               2014-05-14 00:00:00.000 5.00
3           Album3               2014-05-14 00:00:00.000 60.00
```

Or if you need an actual join against Prices to get other columns you can do:

```
select 
* 
from Albums a
left join Prices p on 
(
    a.ID = p.AlbumID and 
    p.ID = (select top 1 pp.Id from Prices pp where pp.AlbumId = a.Id and pp.EffDate <= a.PurchaseDate  order by pp.EffDate desc)
)
```

And get this output:

```
ID          Name                 PurchaseDate            ID          AlbumID     Price                                   EffDate
----------- -------------------- ----------------------- ----------- ----------- --------------------------------------- -----------------------
1           Album1               2014-05-14 00:00:00.000 1           1           5.00                                    2014-01-01 00:00:00.000
2           Album2               2014-05-14 00:00:00.000 2           2           5.00                                    2014-01-01 00:00:00.000
3           Album3               2014-05-14 00:00:00.000 4           3           60.00                                   2014-04-25 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Romero- Thanks for your suggestion, but it doesn't work. The result of your query is: 1 Album1 2014-05-14 60.00;
2 Album2 2014-05-14 60.00;
3 Album3 2014-05-14 60.00;

Comment: Just added another approach, with an actual join. Not the most elegant queries, but they do work :)

Comment: It works! Thank you Sooo much! I wasted most of the day on this silly problem!

Comment: Your answer doesn't show EffDate, which I don't REALLY need... but I wonder if there is a way of showing it too?

Comment: Correct, that's why I added the second approach as well, just in case, which returns all columns for both Album and Price